# How to convert webm video file to 3gp?

Tags: webm

Is any way to convert webm video file into 3gp using any Ubuntu package. My file size is above 55 mb so not supported by online conversion?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with ffmpeg

good to know:
The 3GP file format stores video streams as H.263 or H.264 codecs and various audio streams format are allowed.

Important limitation of this format is the resolution of the H.263 video stream. As 3GP format was developed to work on 3G mobile phones, it can work only with sizes of 128x96, 176x144, 352x288, 704x576 or 1408x1152 pixels.

**Native valid 3GP format**

```
ffmpeg -i inputVideo.avi \
  -f 3gp -vcodec h263 -vf scale=352x288 \
  -acodec amr_nb -ar 8000 -ac 1 \
outputVideo.3gp

-f 3gp : Output file format is 3GP.
-vcodec h263 : Output file will use H.263 codec for video stream.
-acodec amr_nb : Output file will use AMR_NB codec for audio stream.
-vf scale=352x288 : Resize the image to a supported resolution
-acodec amr_nb : Specifies output audio codec
-ar 8000 : Convert audio streams into 8000Hz audio streams. This is required by the AMR_NB encoder.
-ac 1 : Transform audio from stereo into mono. This is also required by the AMR_NB encoder.
```

Complicated?
Yes, it is... With luck, 3GP has been extended to support H264 : no more image size limitation and a bunch of audio codecs supported.

**Using H.264 video codec and AAC audio codec**

```
ffmpeg -i inputVideo.avi -f 3gp -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac outputVideo.3gp

-f 3gp : output file will be using 3GP format.
-vcodec libx264 : use libx264 encoder to produce H.264 encoded streams.
-acodec aac : audio stream will be encoded using AAC encoder.
```